# Assign value of the button to global variables on click, declared outside of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x=0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div button").on("click", function(event) {
        x = $(this).html();
    }) ;
}) ;
console.log(x);
```

I have 5 buttons inside a div element I want the value of fhe button on click whrn they clicked by assigning it to a variable at outside of the function.

[image]

Comment: can you add your HTML snippet

Comment: Of course this does not work as `console.log` executes __before__ you even managed to click a button. But still `x` holds correct value.

Comment: but shouldnt be all in document ready?
check how export works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Answer (score 1):

So.. Erm.. What you want to do is.. When Button X is clicked, you want to use the X value as an Index in Arr[X] to display the contens of that in the LST block?

Since you are pulling the data as html, which is like a string of sorts, you need to do a cast to int first before using it as such, I guess.

It would probably be better to add the value as a property so you can write something else than a number on the button..

And don't forget that arrays count from 0, and your buttons count from 1, so you would need to subtract 1 to get the first element of arr. Or you could just add an empty element to your arr like:

```
var arr = [{rId:0, hNo:""}, ...
// In which case you wouldn't need to subtract 1.
```

In any case on point with your current line, it would be:

```
$('div button').click(function (event) {
   var x = parseInt($(this).html()) - 1;
   $('#lst').html(arr[x].rId + " " + arr[x].hNo);
});
```

If you were going to use the value of button it would be like:

HTML:

```
<button value='1'>Click this amazing button that blows your mind..</button>
```

Script:

```
$('div button').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('#lst').html(arr[x].rId + " " + arr[x].hNo);
});
```

If I got you right, that is.

Answer (score 0):

When you correct all the small spelling errors then code actually works fine, as you can see I've moved the `console.log(x)` inside your function so you can actually see that x is being set.

`Var x=0;` => `var x=0;`
`$document. Ready(function() {` => `$(document).ready(function() {`
`$("div button"). On("click", function(event) {` => `$("div button").on("click", function(event) {`
`Console.log(x);` => `console.log(x);`

```
var x = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div button").on("click", function(event) {
    x = $(this).html();
    console.log(x);
  });
});
```

**Note:** *if you are having problems getting the value of x outside the click function, then you need to provide us with more information about what you want to do with it or show us more of your jquery code.*

**demo**

```js
var x = 0;
var arr = [{rId: 1,hNo:"A31"},{rId: 2,hNo:"A32"},{rId: 2,hNo:"A33"}]
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div button").on("click", function(event) {
    x = $(this).text().replace("button","");
    document.getElementById("First").innerHTML = arr[x] != undefined ? arr[x].rId + " " + arr[x].hNo : "";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
  <button>button4</button>
  <button>button5</button>
</div>
<div id="First"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But I want that value of x outside of the ready() function.. is it possible ?

Comment: @SehzadaSohanKumar If you read the "Note" part of my answer. How do you want to do with the x value?

Comment: Sir now I have added the image. As u can see that i want to display the object present inside  the array whose index value depends upon the text-node value of clicked button.

Comment: Now I think u can picturies it what I want to do with this code...basically I want to develop a SINGLE PAGE APPLICATION in which by inserting the text value of a clicked button into an array as index of it to display the respective object present at that index no.

Comment: Thank u so much sir...it's working fine...but can I write this code in one file and export its members to another file ?